# Slow Query With Large Table

Tags: sql

I have a table with about 250,000,000 rows of data.  The table gets written to once every morning around 8AM.  This is a SQL Azure instance with the "S4" package level.  I am trying to pull some data out of the table and it's extremely slow.  There is only a clustered index on the table.  Right now the following query takes about 25 minutes to run and I have limited the dates greatly.  I really need to run this for at least a week of time, but it's killing me with performance.  Does anyone have suggestions on what I can maybe try?  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
SELECT BusinessDate,
       UnitNumber,
       UnitName,
       POSItemCode AS PLU,
       POSItemDescription AS MenuItem,
       RevenueCategoryDescription AS SalesCategory,
       POSOrderModeDescription AS OrderType,
       SUM (COUNT) AS NumSold,
       SUM (ExtendedSalesPrice) AS ValueSold
  FROM dbo.POSSales
 GROUP 
    BY BusinessDate,
       UnitNumber,
       UnitName,
       RevenueCategoryDescription,
       POSItemCode,
       POSItemDescription,
       POSOrderModeDescription
   HAVING (BusinessDate BETWEEN CONVERT (DATETIME,
                                         '2019-07-26 00:00:00',
                                         102)
                            AND CONVERT (DATETIME,
                                         '2019-07-28 00:00:00',
                                         102))
      AND (SUM (ExtendedSalesPrice) <> 0)
```

Comment: Do you have any influence on the DDL for indexes and partitions?

Comment: I can add or remove anything I need from this DB.  I am the only one that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Filter on the dates *before* aggregation:

```
SELECT BusinessDate, UnitNumber, UnitName, POSItemCode AS PLU, POSItemDescription AS MenuItem,
       RevenueCategoryDescription AS SalesCategory, POSOrderModeDescription AS OrderType, 
      SUM(Count) AS NumSold, 
      SUM(ExtendedSalesPrice) AS ValueSold
FROM  dbo.POSSales
WHERE BusinessDate >= '2019-07-26' AND
      BusinessDate < '2019-07-29' 
GROUP BY BusinessDate, UnitNumber, UnitName, RevenueCategoryDescription,
         POSItemCode, POSItemDescription, POSOrderModeDescription
HAVING SUM(ExtendedSalesPrice) <> 0;
```

Comment: @jpistolero02 please post back after you try this, I'm interested in the results.

Comment: Also, since he wants to do it once at week, maybe he could use **VIEW**

Comment: I tried the code as suggested and it still took 25:14.

Comment: @jpistolero02 . . . That is quite strange.  I would expect something to be different, moving the dates into the `WHERE` clause.  May SQL  Server is smart enough to push the filtering before the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have added an index on BusinessDate,UnitNumber,RevenueCategoryID and POSOrderModeID. The same query is now down to 1:30.  It's getting much better!